# Imagick PHP: Setting geodata EXIF, but it's not being recognised?

Tags: php, geolocation, imagick, exif

I use PHP with Imagick to add EXIF metadata to a PNG, but no EXIF viewer actually aknowledges as legit data, saying there is no Geo data.

```
$imagick->setImageProperty('exif:GPSVersionID', '2, 2, 0, 0');
$imagick->setImageProperty('exif:GPSInfo', rand(100,999));
$imagick->setImageProperty('exif:GPSTimeStamp', '8/1, 27/1, 51/1');
$imagick->setImageProperty('exif:GPSLatitude', '22/1, 19/1, 539999999/10000000');
$imagick->setImageProperty('exif:GPSLongitude', '114/1, 1/1, 42/1');
$imagick->setImageProperty('exif:GPSLatitudeRef', 'N');
$imagick->setImageProperty('exif:GPSLongitudeRef', 'E');
$imagick->writeImage('public/uploads/avatar.jpg');
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have a look at `exiftool` http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ or maybe `exiv2` http://www.exiv2.org

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick - the underlying library below Imagick does not save updated [Exif information](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/55).

> Exif values are not persisted. We only read them and you can 'change' them but we don't update the exif profile when the file is being saved.

You'll need to use a different tool for that.